# How to configure Twig to find templates?

Tags: php, twig, slim

I am using Twig with Slim, and am getting the following error:

> Warning: file_get_contents(application/templates/config.html): failed
>   to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /var/www/testing/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Loader/Filesystem.php on
>   line 131

The script below is located in `/var/www/testing/html/index.php`, and I have verified that the template exists at `/var/www/testing/application/templates/config.html`.

```
$container['view'] = function ($c) {
    $view = new \Slim\Views\Twig('../application/templates', [
        //'cache' => 'path/to/cache'    // See auto_reload option
        'debug' => true,
        'strict_variables'=> true
    ]);
    $view->addExtension(new \Slim\Views\TwigExtension(
        $c['router'],
        $c['request']->getUri()
    ));
    $view->addExtension(new \Twig_Extension_Debug());
    return $view;
};

$app->get('/config', function (Request $request, Response $response) {
    return $this->view->render($response, 'config.html',[]);
});
```

Line 131 is shown below and returns `config.html`.

```
public function getSource($name)
{
    return file_get_contents($this->findTemplate($name));
}
```

I have used this same script in another similar server (however, maybe different PHP version and php.ini and httpd.conf may be different), and do not have this issue?

Obviously, I have configured something incorrectly.  How should I configure Twig to find templates?

Comment: It complains about `points.html`, not `config.html`.

Comment: @AlexBlex  Complains about all of them.  My bad.  I will edit the original post.

Comment: Ah, fair enough. Try to use absolute path then. Something like `new \Slim\Views\Twig(__DIR__.'/../application/templates',....`

Comment: @AlexBlex  That works.  Thanks.  Why would one server work with relative addresses, yet not the other?

Comment: Yeah, if anyone could explain, id would be a good answer.

Comment: The reason why one server might work with relative ones, while another one won't is because some hosting providers disable relative paths due to security reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's a problem (bug?) I've encountered last week, and @geggleto solved it.

This is because of Twig update from `v1.26.1` from `1.24.2`.

This is how Twig grabbed in `1.24.2` (method `Twig_Loader_Filesystem::normalizeName`):

```
protected function normalizeName($name)
{
    return preg_replace('#/{2,}#', '/', str_replace('\\', '/', (string) $name));
}
```

And this is how it grabs file in `1.26.1`:

```
private function normalizePath($path)
{
    $parts = explode('/', str_replace('\\', '/', $path));
    $isPhar = strpos($path, 'phar://') === 0;
    $new = array();
    foreach ($parts as $i => $part) {
        if ('..' === $part) {
            array_pop($new);
        } elseif ('.' !== $part && ('' !== $part || 0 === $i || $isPhar && $i < 3)) {
            $new[] = $part;
        }
    }
    return implode('/', $new);
}
```

See that `array_pop($new);` line? That's the one that ruins use of relative path.

@geggleto suggested to use absolute path instead of relative, and it worked:

```
\Slim\Views\Twig(__DIR__.'/../application/templates')
```

To sum up: this happens because of Twig new version.

Comment: Sure enough!  I updated composer on the first server, and now it doesn't work there either.  Nice to know, however, I am getting consistent results.  Reading over the Twig change log, they don't highlight the issue.  Thank you for your comprehensive answer.